# Should I use a modifier, 'controlled by an operating rod', or a gerund, 'controlled by operating a rod'?

Tags: gerunds

> 1. The crane is contactor controlled by an operating rod.
> 2. The crane is contactor controlled by operating a rod.

Can operating act as a gerund in the first sentence?

Can 'operating rod' be a terminology?

Comment: I would read 'operating' in the first sentence as a participle, not a gerund - it sounds as though it's describing what kind of rod is involved.

Answer (score 1):

**To my (American) ear, the following choice looks best:**

> 2b.  The crane is contractor-controlled by operating a rod.

"Contactor" does not sound natural.  (Also, my spell-checker does not recognize "contactor" as word.)  I expect that you mean either "contractor" or "contact".  A "contractor" is either a business entity that is paid to perform contracts, or a person who works for such an entity.  A "contact" is an electrical surface that is part of a switch.  In the context of controlling a crane, I expect that you mean a "contractor" -- a person who operates a crane, on behalf of a company that is fulfilling a contract.

I would diagram this sentence as follows:

> <Subject> is <past tense verb-phrase acting as an adjective> <subordinate clause that describes the verb>

where

> <Subject> = <determiner> <noun> = "The crane"
>
> <Past tense verb-phrase acting as an adjective> = <secondary subject>hyphen<past tense verb> = "contractor-controlled"
>
> <subordinate clause that describes the verb> = <how the "contractor" controls the crane> = by <gerund> <noun phrase> = "by operating a rod".

In the last section, the <noun phrase> = <determiner> <noun> = "a rod".

**Terminology**

Yes, an "operating rod" does sound like a natural piece of terminology.  I am familiar with "control rods", "cam shafts", and "operating temperatures".  Although I am not familiar with the term "operating rod", it seems analogous to these phrases I am familiar with.  As [MrTheWalrus](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/5069) points out, this use of "operating" is functioning as an adjective.  I would therefore re-write the first proposed sentence to have a verb instead of "by":

> 1b. The crane is contractor-controlled using an operating rod.

Sentence 1b does not sound as natural (to me) as sentence 2b.

Comment: hi, thank you for you answer, appreciated it! There are several results of 'operating rod' appears as an Formula 1 terminology on the internet. Do you think it is possible that the writer of the original sentence wanted the words to be used in that sense? Will that make any sense to you?